# vue js site showing blank page in production

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

vue js site showing blank page in production, while it is running properly in development mode after i do npm run build it goes blank when i run it... 
what can i do? for that? everything is running correctly in development and and there is not any error in both modes 
[image]
[image]

Comment: No errors in Chrome console?

Comment: Your `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js` should precede `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Post the console error

Answer (score 0):

Try load popper.min.js locally instead of cdn.

```
Access to script at 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js' from origin 'https://kamsham.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: i did solve that issue by removing variable..... the variable was initializing after the page is rendered so i could'nt see it

Comment: what variable @sahamnadeem, I'm currently having the same issue..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65698801/page-modal-is-not-displaying-in-production-build-executable-vue-electron-vueti