# Page/Modal is not Displaying in production build (executable) Vue-Electron-Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-router, electron-builder

In Development mode (npm run electron:serve), Modal is showing.. but when it comes to production (executable) it shows nothing.

Production Mode:
[image]

Development Mode:
[image]

In my vue file I have this code:

```
<v-dialog v-model="LoginDialog" persistent>
    --contents here--
</v-dialog>


data:() => ({
    LoginDialog: true,
})
```

I really have no Idea on what's causing this in production.

Comment: What is your vuetify version, I had a similar problem like you, but after updating vuetify, it was resolved. You can read about that issue here: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9175

Comment: @MarioKlisanic v2.2.11

Comment: That's not it then, this issue was fixed in version in versions after 2.1.0

Comment: @MarioKlisanic the problem was in vue router... I removed history mode

Answer (score 0):

Remove `history` mode from the router.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code.